# Ideal generated by given integers verification.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, integers

The question reads:

> Find the positive generator of the smallest ideal in $\mathbf Z$ containing the following ideals:
>
> a. $(4)$ and $(18)$. My answer is $(m)=(4)$.
>
> b. $(6)$ and $(35)$. My answer $(m)=(3)$.

My reasoning for these solutions is that the ideal for the ring of integers is a set closed under addition and multiplication where $A=\{k(m):k\in\mathbf Z\}$ and $A$ is the ideal. Since the positive generator should be the smallest containing I chose $(4)$ for "a" and $(3)$ for "b". I believe there is a word for these numbers ($\gcd$ or $\operatorname{lcm}$?).

Additionally, how would the solution differ if the question had instead asked

> "Find a (single) generator of the ideal in $\mathbf Z$ containing the following ideals"?

Thank you for your time and guidance!

Comment: Your answers are not right I'm afraid. It is true that an equivalent formulation of this question is to find the gcd of the two numbers, but 4 is not the gcd of 4 and 18. Similarly, 6 is not the gcd of 6 and 35.

Comment: Okay. Would the answer for a. be m=2 and b. be m=1?

Comment: Yes, that's more like it!

Comment: Could you answer the second question as well? Not to sound ungrateful.

Comment: Yes, if you are asked to find a single generator, then in case a) you could use $2$ or $-2$. In case b) $1$ or $-1$. Note that in case b) you are generating the unit ideal $(1)$ which is the whole ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You have two choices because multiplication by a unit (the units of $\mathbb{Z}$ being $1$ and $-1$) doesn't change the ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If $m,n \in \Bbb Z$, then the smallest ideal containing $(m)$ and $(n)$ is the ideal $(\gcd(m,n))$. For (a) this means the ideal $(2)$, while for (b) this means the ideal $(1) = \Bbb Z$ (because $6$ and $35$ are coprime).

Each ideal $(m) \subseteq \Bbb Z$ is generated by any invertible element of $\Bbb Z$ multiplied by $m$. Since the only invertible elements of $\Bbb Z$ are $1$ and $-1$, the ideal $(m)$ is generated by $m$, as well as by $-m$.

In your examples, $(2)$ is generated by $2$, and is also generated by $-2$; clearly the positive generator is $2$. Similarly, the positive generator of $\Bbb Z$ is $1$.

If the question had been modified by dropping the positivity requirement, any of $2$ and $-2$ (and, respectively, $1$ and $-1$) would have been a correct answer.

Comment: I see that now. I had recognized that either the positive or negative versions of the integer would generate the ideal, but I had actually looked at a question. Also, thank you for the reformatting.